# UITextView displays keyboard only after touching in particular area?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitextview

When I increase the frame of `UITextView` based on content size programmatically in keyboard hide notification delegate method,
The textview height is increased perfectly.But when I touch  the `UITextView` bottom line, the keyboard is not coming.If i touch the area which was before
increasing frame or in actual first frame area, the keyboard is coming.How can I enable userinteraction in all area of `UITextView`?

```
      Textview is as scrollview<---view1<---view2<---UItextview
```

Even If i increase the height of view2 and UItextview in xib, the same problem is coming.
I have disabled scrolling facility of UITextview

Answer (score 0):

After increase the height of your `UITextView` write this bellow line , may be its problem that some view is front of `UITextView`...

```
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:yourTextView];
```

Comment: on which view you add this textview??

Comment: ohhh man that is the problem... set frame of that whole view with contentsize of textview and bring at front ...

Comment: @mirdad problem solved now?? just increase frame of your view2 and view1 and also UIScrollView with content of textview .. its working now??